# Unable to retrieve data from firebase

Tags: objective-c, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from firebase and tried different solutions but snapshot value is returning null. The data is created by "childbyAutoID" and I want to retrieve it using current uid.

[image: Picture from Firebase]

Below are three solutions, I tried

Solution 1:

```
    NSString *ID = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser.uid;
    [[[self.databaseRef child:@"User-Subscription"] child:ID] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

        NSDictionary *childData = snapshot.value;
        NSLog(@"%@",childData); //Returns null
        // ...
    } withCancelBlock:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
    }];
```

Solution 2:

```
    NSString *ID = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser.uid; //User ID
    [[[self.databaseRef child:@"User-Subscription"] childByAutoId] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

        NSDictionary *childData = snapshot.value;
        NSLog(@"%@",childData); //Return null
        // ...
    } withCancelBlock:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
    }];
```

Solution 3:

```
    NSString *ID = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser.uid; //User ID 
    [[[[self.databaseRef child:@"User-Subscription"] childByAutoId] queryEqualToValue:ID]observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

        NSDictionary *childData = snapshot.value;
        NSLog(@"%@",childData); //Return null
        // ...
    } withCancelBlock:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
    }];
```

Any help in pointing out mistake is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that is returning the data.

```
[[self.databaseRef child:@"User-Subscription"] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

    NSDictionary *childData = snapshot.value;
    NSLog(@"%@",childData); 
    // ...
} withCancelBlock:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

But now problem is, how I query it using "subs_ID" if there are 2,3 user subscriptions that are generated by childbyAutoID?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. i tried this solution and i didn't get a result. is there anything your doing with databaseRef initializations? i can't figure out any other reason that my version is not receiving posts.

Comment: I am doing nothing with databaseRef initilizations but you also need authentication. As, I am using FB login with firebase therefore it is automatically authenticated. Also you need to check your child name that it is spelled correctly.